# PHP Netbeans breakpoint only on running code

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans

How can I set a breakpoint (Netbeans) in a function, where I don't use code in order to check a variable.

Here is an example with a fictional (wordpress) hook within a class:

```php
function my_example($my_variable){
  // -> Breakpoint to check the variable $my_variable not working
}

add_action("do_example", my_example);
```

Within the class or a nested function, I've got some errors with `echo`. If I only use the variable like this:

```php
function my_example($my_variable){
  $my_variable; // -> Breakpoint not working
}
```

It will not stop within the function.

Can I use something like Console.log in javascript or Console.Write in C#?

I found [error_log](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) but this is not really what I want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method breakpoints.

To do this:

- open the `Window -> Debugging -> Breakpoints` window.
- сlick `Create new breakpoint`.
- In the dialog box in the `Breakpoint type` drop-down list select `Method` and in the `Method Name` field write the name of your function.